# "! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode. "ERROR

Tags: table-of-contents, errors

While I attempt to create a catalog, an error pops up stating that

> You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.
>   \enddocument ... \endgroup \deadcycles \z@ @@end.

What might be the problem here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{SOME WORDS} SOME WORDS
\subsection{SOME WORDS} SOME WORDS
\subsubsection{SOME WORDS} SOME WORDS
\paragraph{SOME WORDS} SOME WORDS
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume this only occurs when you call `\tableofcontents`. That is, if you remove it, this compile without problem? Regardless, try and delete the `.toc` and `.aux` files associated with your project and try again. Does it fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. I've tried your advice, but not work that well. And it's weird that I can successfully compile it before I call \tableofcontents, however, now I remove it though, it still can't not compile successfully.

Comment: I get no error from the posted code. If you get an error from that please show the full log